# How to make a link inside an overflow:hidden listelement clickable?

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I'm trying to make a link clickable inside of an list element. The list elements are styled with an `:after` pseudo element, because of hiding the last characters inside the link.

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgztmqp6/)

I need pure css solutions. I can make it work using JavaScript.

Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but i'm really new to stackoverflow. [http://jsfiddle.net/cgztmqp6/](http://jsfiddle.net/cgztmqp6/)

Comment: Edit your post and paste a link to JSFIDDLE in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why you are using an `:after` pseudo like that or what you are trying to accomplish there.

But anyways, inorder to fix it and make the links clickable, you need to use `pointer-events: none;` on your `:after` pseudo and that should work for you.

Update your stylesheet like :

```
ul li:after {
    content:'';
    pointer-events: none; /* Add this */

    /* Other properties */
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cgztmqp6/13/)

Comment: pointer-events is a way to go. But keep in mind that it isn't supported by IE10 and below. http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events

Comment: @Demnogonis Thanks for the caniuse link, missed that out in my answer this time

Answer (score 0):

This is happening not due to `overflow:hidden;` but due to the fact that your `:after` pseudo element is overlaying all other content 'blocking' the links.

As such, simply add `pointer-events:none;` to the `:after` pseudo so it doesnt register mouse events, which instead are 'passed through' to the links below

### [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/cgztmqp6/12/)

[**More on `pointer-events` from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

> The CSS property pointer-events allows authors to control under what
>   circumstances (if any) a particular graphic element can become the
>   target of mouse events.
>
> In addition to indicating that the element is not the target of mouse
>   events, **the value `none` instructs the mouse event to go "through" the
>   element and target whatever is "underneath" that element instead.**

With that in mind- depending on required browser support- pointer events may not suffice.